# Simple SQL query

Tags: sql, database, aggregate-functions

I have a table, with these columns:

```
ID  |  Data
```

How to find out which record has highest ID?

Answer (score 9):

To get the largest ID:

```
select max(ID) from myTable
```

To get a record that has the largest ID:

```
select *
from MyTable
where ID = (Select max(ID) from myTable)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select max(ID) from tablename
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
    from YourTable
    where ID = (select max(ID) from YourTable)
```

Answer (score 1):

As well as max, you can use TOP on SQL Server

```
select TOP 1 * from myTable order by id desc
```

For joint top

```
select TOP 1 WITH TIES * from myTable order by id desc
```

Other engines have LIMIT not TOP. This can give the whol record without a separate MAX sub-query too